# Connecting flights: separate bookings

Tags: visas, transit, bookings, tanzanian-citizens

I have booked the following flights:

1. Flight from London to Milan (MXP) with British Airways, arriving at Terminal 1.
2. Flight from Milan (MXP) to Dar es Salaam via Jeddah with Saudia, departing from the same Terminal (Terminal 1).

These flights have been booked separately - the onward flight departs three hours after I land at MXP on the same day.

NB:

- I am a Tanzanian citizen holding a British residence permit.
- I only have hand luggage
- I will check in online for my second flight (so the boarding pass will be available on my phone prior to my first first)

Can someone tell me whether or not I will have any issues transiting through MXP airside during the layover (can I just wait in the Transit area for flight 2)? The [website](https://www.esteri.it/en/servizi-consolari-e-visti/ingressosoggiornoinitalia/visto_ingresso/paesi_soggetti_visto_transito_aeroportuale/) of the Italian Foreign Ministry suggests that I will not require an Airport Transit Visa but I remember reading elsewhere that certain airlines can deny boarding under such circumstances.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: In addition to the Schengen visa issue raised by Willeke, 3 hours for a self-transfer is risky, especially when the most expensive and least frequent of the two flights is the second one. Remember that if the first flight is delayed and you don’t make it in time for the second one, your ticket is very likely to be cancelled (including the return flight, if any), and then you need to book and pay for a new flight, at last minute prices (usually a lot more expensive).

Answer (score 2):

BA can, and is even likely to, deny you access to the first flight if you do not have the right to enter Italy, which means a full Schengen zone visa.

Airlines can allow you on a flight if you can convince them you will leave the country they fly you to but it is not a right, and even when you have their permission on paper the ground crew for the airline can stop you getting on.

I checked for you on a link from this question/answer:
[Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

You need to be allowed into Italy as if you have a layover or visit there and I see you not being allowed in without a visa.